Unbiased randomness from a coin toss source with adversarial bias
Suppose Alice would like to make Bob toss a coin to extract a random bit. Unfortunately, in my setting, Bob can toss the coin up to $k$ times and reveal the result of just one of the tosses within these $k$ tosses i.e. he can bias the result to heads or tails as he chooses.
The Von Neumann trick using a biased coin where you toss till you get HT or TH and label those as H and T doesn't work here because Bob can essentially change the coin every time. However, he cannot guarantee a result since he is bounded by $k$.
Is there a way for Alice to get an unbiased random bit from this setup?
EDIT: Just to clarify, Bob only gives Alice one toss result, even though he can toss up to $k$ times.

Are you happy with negligible bias, or do you want perfectly unbiased bits?

Negligible bias would be fine too.

Then my answer is essentially the same as that of kodlu, except that the numbers in his answer look a bit off, I'll add an answer on the same lines

@GeoffroyCouteau That answer should be perfectly unbiased though, as far as I understand things?

It is not! I hope my answer will make it clear.

The experiment you describe is perfectly equivalent to the following experiment:

First, the experiment decides whether the coin will be fair or arbitrary, with $p = \Pr[\mathsf{Fair}] = 2/2^k$ and $1-p = \Pr[\mathsf{Arbitrary}] = 1-2/2^k$.
Bob chooses an arbitrary value $b^* \in \{0,1\}$
If the experiment picked $\mathsf{Fair}$, it returns a fair random coin $b$. Else, it returns $b^*$.

Take a minute to convince yourself that this is perfectly equivalent to the setting you described. Now, this means Alice receives random bits $b$ which are either random (with probability $p$) or arbitrary (with probability $1-p$).
From there, there are two options depending on some unspecified aspects of your question: does Bob have a memory of all previous coin tosses he sent to Alice, or is Bob's arbitrary strategy only a function of the $k$ tosses he sees locally. Put differently: at round $n$ is Bob given the previous $b_i$'s (for $i=1$ to $n-1$ when choosing $b^*_n$? The answer to your question varies significantly depending on which of these settings you assume.
Setting 1: $b^*_n$ is independent of $b_1, \cdots, b_{n-1}$
Alice simply asks for a large enough number of bits $n(k)$ and outputs $b = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n(k)}$. To see why this works, observe that if at least a single bit $b_i$ was fair, as all previous and subsequent bits are independent of $b_i$ (because Bob is memoryless), then $b$ is a uniformly random coin.
Then, what is the probability that at least one bit is fair? The answer is given by a calculation: Let $X_i = 1$ if the $i$th bit is fair, and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Write $X = \sum_{i=1}^{n(k)} X_i$. We have $\Pr[X = 0] = (1-p)^{n(k)} = (1-2^{-k+1})^{n(k)}$. Via standard inequalities, we get
$\Pr[X = 0] \leq e^{n(k)/2^{k-1}}$,
so by setting $n(k) = t / 2^{k-1}$, Alice gets an unbiased bit with probability at least $1-e^{-t}$ (or, equivalently, she gets a bit with bias at most $e^{-t}$).
Note (see correction to the note below): n-l-i's answer seemed to assume that after $2^{k-1}$ $b_i$'s you always get one that is unbiased, but this is incorrect. I assume otherwise that n-l-i meant XORing with the verb "combine" and assumed the setting where $b^*_n$ is independent of previous $b_i$'s, so his answer is along the lines of the one I sketch here.
Correction to the note (added later): n-l-i pointed out in the comment that my assumption about their answer was incorrect and that it did not make any of the two assumptions I said it made. My guess came from trying to reconstruct the line of thought that led to the answer; see the discussion in the comments for why I think the answer is incorrect anyway.
Setting 2: $b^*_n$ is not independent of $b_1, \cdots, b_{n-1}$
Then that's a whole other story! We now have a source of bits $b_1, b_2, \cdots$, where the bits are guaranteed to contain some entropy, but each $b_i$ could depend (in a complex way) on $b_1 \cdots, b_{i-1}$. What we want in an extractor: a function $\mathsf{Ext}$ that takes $b_1, \cdots, b_n$ as inputs and produces an almost-uniform bit. I strongly recommend reading this chapter from Salil Vadhan's book on pseudorandomness if you are interested in the question.
In short, the source you are considering is a Santha-Vazirani source. Unfortunately, there exist Santha-Vazirani sources for which it is possible to prove that there does not exist any non-trivial extractor! (See proposition 6.6 in the chapter and also this paper). Now, your source is not an arbitrary Santha-Vazirani source and it could be that for your specific source, there is a deterministic solution, but it's far from obvious to me.
However, there's a way around if you are OK with giving to Alice an initial seed: a short string $s$ of truly uniform bits that she knows at the start of the experiment. Given such a seed, Alice can use a seeded extractor $\mathsf{Ext}(s, b_1, \cdots, b_n)$, and such extractors provably exist for all weak sources (sources such that $b_1 \cdots b_n$ are guaranteed to contain some amount of min-entropy, which your source is -- see the chapter if you want more details and a definition of what min-entropy is, I don't want to make this answer too much longer). Using a seeded extractor, she can extract an unbounded number almost-unbiased bits (reusing the same initial seed $s$ every time). The literature contains many constructions of seeded extractors with various parameters, the most common being the ones implied by the leftover hash lemma. I'll let you work out the parameters for such constructions (or ask another question) if this is the solution you're looking for :)

Your assumptions about my answer are incorrect. I don't assume that after $2k−1 b_i$s we always get one that is unbiased, and I didn't mean XORing by "combine", and I didn't assume that each $b^∗_n$ is independent of previous $b_i$s. If you don't know and something is unclear then ask. I assume there is a constant chance that each result is unbiased, and by combining a number of such results in a way that preserves all information we will get an unbiased result. The combining would need to preserve order and not be something that the other party can't easily influence, of which XOR is neither.

My apologies! I misunderstood your point (and also mistakenly attributed your answer to kodlu, who edited it, I should have looked more carefully). I will edit my answer. Note, however, that if you remove any of the two assumptions I thought you made, then your answer provably cannot work, which is the reason why I assumed you were making these assumptions. There is clearly no way to get an unbiased coin from $2^{k-1}$ $b_i$'s simply because there's a (constant) probability that they are all arbitrary, and this is true whatever combine function you use.

Why is that clearly true? And provably? This isn't clear to me, at least. If we know there is a constant chance X of getting a random bit, why would that not be equivalent to getting X random bits each time? Say X=1/6, then we could see it as rolling a dice and getting a random bit if we roll a six and a non-random bit otherwise. The other party cannot influence the dice roll so that randomness can't be discarded. The only thing that makes sense to me is to assume that each bit we generate would be 1/6th random bit. Please explain why this would be wrong and I'd love to see the proof to.

Let's keep you dice example. First, why can't there be a "Combine" function that takes 6 dice rolls and outputs an unbiased bit? Because it could be that all 6 dice rolls are arbitrary. If that happens, the adversary gets to choose the entire input to Combine. Put differently, with probability at least (5/6)^6 = 0.334, the output of Combine is adversarially chosen. You can't have a uniform bit if the adversary can choose its value 33% of the time.

Second, how do you define "1/6th of a random bit"? This is informal, and this informality might be where the confusion comes from. You must define a measure of what it means to contain "1/6th of a random bit". Then what is your measure? Shannon entropy? Min-entropy? The Shannon entropy of your dice source is 0.41, it's min-entropy is 0.13. Neither is 1/6. And it does not work like that: you cannot just put 6 symbols with entropy 1/6 in a deterministic function and get one bit of entropy out of that. If you'd like to discuss it further (it's getting long for comments), let's continue in chat?

Would love to! [chat]

Yes, set up $k = 1$ and assume a fair coin.
Alternatively if $k > 1$, then Alice can perform a HMAC function on Bob's concatenated declarations.  She chooses a password/phrase only known to her. Then she watches one of the output bits, say the most significant one. That's her unbiased random bit. E.g:-
$\text{Bit} = \text{HMAC}_{msb}(\text{secret}, C_0||C_1||\dots||C_n)$ where $C$ are Bob's coin declarations.
Due to pre-image resistance and the avalanche effect, Bob should not be able to predict which coin side to declare. Even if he just infinitely repeats the same side. She's effectively creating a cryptographic pseudo random number generator that Bob cannot influence.
